Test if a specific user is a member of any groups
I'm writing a Powershell script to copy the Active Directory groups from one user to another. I need a way to see if a user (based on the user's SAM Account Name) is a member of any groups or not. All other things I've seen are "how to see the members of a group" or "how to list all members not in a specific group", what I need is to see, as a boolean, if a specific user is part of any groups at all or not. I'm also very new to Powershell and Active Directory, so dumbed-down answers would be appreciated.
Additionally, I don't need to know what groups there are, just if there are any. Lots of similar questions have people wanting to know what groups a specific user is a member of. I don't care, this is for a validity check; if there are no groups for the username entered, prompt the user to put in a new one. I have the code to prompt the user and everything, I just need the condition for the if statement.
I've tried a bunch of similar solutions here on Stack Overflow, and none have worked.

All users get a primary group id assigned on creation (usually either Domain Users or Domain Guests), so a user with no group membership is exceedingly rare. Are you looking for users with absolutely no group memberships including unset primary GID, or "users with no explicit values referenced in the memberOf link attribute"?

"if there are no groups for the username entered, prompt the user to put in a new one." - beware that security groups in Active Directory are usually used to encode access control models - allowing a user to arbitrarily pick and choose their own group memberships could land you in hot water. If I was a malicious actor I'd simply ask you to add me to an admin group and now I have control over your domain :)

The latter. I forgor about Domain Users. My script will copy groups from one user to another, so if there are no groups to copy, I'm trying to make it not waste anyone's time and tell them they can't before they even try

Not a new group, a new username to copy from @MathiasR.Jessen

alright well I received word that this is actually not necessary so never mind for my sake, I'll leave the question open in case someone else needs it though

Pls try this cmdlet:
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership
You can format the output with format-table including the properties you require.
Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-adprincipalgroupmembership?view=windowsserver2022-ps
“Gets the Active Directory groups that have a specified user, computer, group, or service account.
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity Administrator
distinguishedName : CN=Domain Users,CN=Users,DC=Fabrikam,DC=com GroupCategory : Security GroupScope : Global name : Domain Users objectClass : group objectGUID : 86c0f0d5-8b4d-4f35-a867-85a006b92902 SamAccountName : Domain Users SID : S-1-5-21-41432690-3719764436-1984117282-513 etc...”
